Challenges with 45 degree build orientation
My question here is two-fold.  I'm working on a project that requires I print tensile testing specimen based off ASTM standards.  I have the necessary dimensionality for my specimen, and I've had no issues printing it in a Bambu X1E at both a 0 and 90 angle build orientation.  However, printing this specimen at 45 degrees has been a challenge.
There are multiple issues I'm running into, and most of it relates to what I would describe as sagging.  I believe it's being caused by an uneven speed and flow across the printing process.  Would anyone be able to explain or reference me to specific information that can teach me how to equilibrate these process parameters across the entire length of the build?
Edit:
So I don't see a way to upload a .stl file but here's the gist of what I've developed so far!

ISO Polymer Tensile Test specimen on Printables

Please add images of the specimen, certainly in the 45 degree angle you are printing. E.g. are you usint support or not? Also, it might be benificial to post your print settings, to get an idea, look at Helpful Templates / Help us help you!.

Hey Oscar, sure thing!  Give me some time and I'll update my post later tonight.

45 degrees is too steep to cause sagging in normal scenarios, so this is definitely a problem related to how the specimen is supported, and its length/shape. Can you post a photo of the specimen with the problem (preferably two, one still with supports, as seen from the support side, one after support removal) ?
I suspect reducing support gap would help but can't say anything for sure without seeing the issue.

As these are tensile specimen, I'm assuming you print these solid? Please explain why you need them under 45°, flat with give you the highest tensile strength, upright the lowest, 45° will be in between. So if you design a part for upright, you're always on the safe side. Know you can change the orientation of the infill. I'm just pondering what your infill is on the flat specimen? Always in one direction or 0°, 90° alternating? What infill are you looking for in the 45° specimen? You could print it on the side and change infill direction to mimic 45° angle printing.

@0scar I'm attempting to use 100% infill for the purposes of this project.  That may make things harder... I'd assume changing the raster orientation on a 100% infill object doesn't do much.  So, if I were to follow your suggestion: printing on the side and adjusting raster angle to mimic a 45-degree build orientation, because the infill is 100% it wouldn't model a 45-degree build orientation?

Taking into account that the outline walls are negligible w.r.t. the infill, the infill is the load bearing material. Indeed, it isn't exactly the same, but it comes close, and you should only print +/+45°.

Hi Oscar, thank you for your advice.  I'll see what I can do with that idea.  Also what did you mean by, "you should only print +/+ 45-degrees"?

You can determine the direction of the infill path, normally it is 0/90, but you can change the direction in Cura, -45/45 will give you 0/90 rotated by 45 degrees. So, +45/+45 will give you uniform direction. Beware of the orientation of the specimen on the plate. See e.g. Infill Line Direction.
